# Is there any spring support for kafka 0.8.2.2?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I'd like to use spring support to integrate with kafka. the server version is 0.8.2.2 but all the spring projects i could find uses newer kafka. even spring-kafka-1.0.0 uses kafka 0.9.0.1. and i read that kafka client's is not backward compatible. so the question is: is there any spring support for older kafka version or i have to get official kafka client and do it by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Cloud Stream `1.0.x` versions supports kafka binder with kafka version `0.8.2.2`. Spring Integration Kafka `1.3.x` version also uses Kafka `0.8.2.2`.

Comment: thank you. spring integration `1.3.x` uses `0.8.2.1` but AFAIK it's safe to bump: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/tree/v1.3.0.RELEASE but i can find no information about versions in spring-cloud-stream docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/ could you provide any link?

Comment: I don't see it explicitly specified in that documentation as I think at that time we only had support for 0.8.x.x. You can see the version anyway here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/1.0.x/spring-cloud-stream-binders/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/pom.xml#L17

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring-integration 1.3.x with spring-integration-kafka and use the spring-integration-java-dsl to integrate with Kafka 0.8.2.2

E.g. if you use maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you are using the high level API this will work pretty good for you. If you need low level support to manage your own partition pointers and leader election it will be a little bit more difficult to find documentation on those parts.